# If statement, first condition's value is within range of second conditional but it returns first conditional

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a QA sampling calculator using a C=0 sampling plan.
Whenever I input any number and try it, the result I'm provided corresponds to that of a different range.

```js
const sample = parseFloat(this.sampleSize)
const lot = parseFloat(this.lotSize)

if (aqlSelector.value == 0.010) {
    if (this.sampleSize > 0 || this.sampleSize <= 1200) {
        lotQty.innerText = 'All'
        console.log(sample)
        console.log(lot)
    } else if (this.sampleSize >= 1201) {
        lotQty.innerText = '1250'
    }
}
```

[Code after trying different approach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQkuE.png)
[Results I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3SAl.png)

Codepen of whole project: https://codepen.io/cesar-higashi/pen/LYbPwaJ

Comment: Please add a [mcve] _in the question itself. There's too much "noise" in your example and it uses a quite strange type of indentation that makes it hard to read and follow.

Comment: is that better?

Comment: That's not a [mcve]

Comment: Could you tell us the exact result that you get and the result you expect?

Comment: added two pictures, maybe the second one  will answer your question. Basically, if a user inputs a  number and chooses an aql (acceptable quality level) from the selector, the calculator ought to return the sample size the user needs to inspect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!

Turns out, a certain section in the code added a comma (',') to long numbers to make them easier to read, which in turn made them NaN.

I will update the codepen once the project is concluded. To all who took the time, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You have used wrong logical operator
 `if (this.sampleSize > 0 || this.sampleSize <= 1200)`
it should be
`if (this.sampleSize > 0 && this.sampleSize <= 1200)`

With your `||` (or) it returns first for every value greater than 0

Comment: hey, tried that one and didn't solve the problem. Thnks anyways.